# Error in function while using "between" keyword in function body oracle sql?? the error is on 6th line but donot kow how to resolve it?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace function fweight
  (minn in item.weight%type
  ,maxx in item.weight%type
  ,colour in item.color%type)
return number
        is
          total number(5);
        begin
            select count(itemno) into total from weight minn and maxx item where color = colour;
            dbms_output.put_line('The item whose weight is  between '||minn||' and '||maxx ||' is  ');
             return total;
        end;
```

Comment: I don't see that 'between' keyword in that line?

Comment: What is "from weight minn and maxx item where" supposed to be doing? Is that supposed to be joining two tables, or checking item.weight is between the values as part of the where clause, or something else? Including the table definition(s) and sample data and results might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `between`, except within a string literal. The `weight minn and maxx` part of the query isn't valid syntax and doesn't really make sense, either where it is or as part of a `where` clause.

Based on how you've declared the arguments, you might want:

```
select count(itemno) into total
from item
where color = colour
and weight between minn and maxx;
```

Relying on the spelling difference between the argument `colour` and column name `color` looks a bit dangerous; might be better to prefix the argument names to avoid confusion.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b8a51fb27be4354417329b3ff70f16f6) with some made-up data.